# Accounts.registerLoginHandler with passwords in Meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor

I'm new to meteor and am stuck on registering a login handler that lets me use the password to authenticate the user.

I'm working off the code from [http://meteorhacks.com](http://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html)

The server side code is as follows:

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest) {
var userId = null;
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': loginRequest.email, password: loginRequest.password, 'proile.type': loginRequest.type});
if(user) {
  userId = user._id;
}
return { id: userId}
```

This works fine if I take out the password field and just use the email and type ones. How do I get this working with the password as well?

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line, you can't directly search via the plaintext password. You need to verify the password via SRP which is a little tricky as there isn't any documentation on it. Luckily Meteor is open source! A good start is at the `accounts-password` : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js

There already is a package that can do password logins for you (the one the above file is from). You can add it to your project via `meteor add accounts-password`.

Then you could login with **[Meteor.loginWithPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithpassword)**

Comment: Thanks Akshat, what I'm trying to achieve is a login with password that also checks a "type" field. In other words, you can have multiple user/password/type accounts with the same user/password as long as type is different (if that makes sense).

I guess one option is to use the standard login with password called from my handler which then checks the type? I'd rather not duplicate all the existing code naturally. :)