# In Meteor, how to do server side user login check?

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a REST API on Meteor. The mobile clients would send login requests with username and password via POST request. Is there anyway I can do to check the user's information on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meteor.users collection contains all the users information if you are using Meteor's "accounts-base" package.

You should look at the source for the Meteor accounts password system: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js

Also checkout this SO post: [Accounts.registerLoginHandler with passwords in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275322/accounts-registerloginhandler-with-passwords-in-meteor)

Comment: Is there anyway that I can check if the user's password matches the one in the database so that I can let him login from a mobile client?(Say an android app, not mobile web)

Comment: i did not found  Accounts._checkPassword function in my account-password.js file

Answer (score 2):

You can use `api-password` module which validates username and password on the server side:

http://beta.atmospherejs.com/package/api-password

Here is the [blog post](http://blog.avrora.io/2014/03/21/server-side-userpassword-validation-in-meteor/) if you need more details